# VBA Basics - Calling Function From a Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a Function Macro that calculates the days between two dates.  It looks like I have that.

```
Function daysRem(today As Date, eoc As Date) As Integer
    daysRem = Abs(DateDiff("d", today, eoc))
End Function
```

Now, I need to "Call" that function from a Sub to roughly estimate the number of weeks remaining.  I'd like that to be in a message box.  That's where I've hit about 2 hours of frustration.  This has got to be simple, but I just can't figure out what to do.

Comment: `Msgbox daysRem(Date, Date+3)`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I guess I'm just on such a low level that I don't understand what to do with this.  Something like this?'

    Sub weeksRem()
    MsgBox daysRem(Date, Date + 3)
    End Sub

That gives me a compile error.

Comment: Is your difficulty with getting the "number of weeks remaining"? Or something else? What is going wrong? Can you show the code in your Sub?

Comment: My difficulty is in understanding the syntax.  This give me a compile error.

    `Sub weeksRem()
    MsgBox daysRem(Date, Date + 3)
   End Sub`

These are the first functions I've ever written in VBA, and I'm just totally lost.

Comment: The parameter for *'number of weeks'* is not "d".

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: What exactly you want to achive? Add 3 days/weeks to current date? Use DateAdd function

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped.  I get that - I think.  The first bit of code is just to get the dates.  I know you could change the "d" to "ww" and get the number of weeks, but that's not the point of the exercise.  I'm trying to learn about writing a macro function and then calling that with a sub - even if it is a roundabout way of doing a simple thing.

Comment: Hi @M.R.

Here's what I want to do:

1) Write a macro function that calculates the difference between two dates.

2) Write a Sub that uses that calculated number, divides by 7 to get number of weeks, and puts that number in a Message Box.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that illustrates and reproduces the problem you're having. You speak of a message box, but there's no sign of it in your code, so which part are we supposed to answer? How you call a function depends on what you want to do with its return value. If you do `MsgBox "Hello"`, you don't care what the function returned. If you do `result = MsgBox("Get it?", vbYesNo)` then you've stored that return value in some `result` local variable; `MsgBox` is just a function, just like every function you'll ever write. Its full name is `VBA.Interaction.MsgBox`.

Comment: Why can't you simply take `Date1` - `Date2`? No special functions needed, this will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub DisplayDaysDiff()
 Dim dtDate1 as Date
 Dim dtDate2 as Date

 dtDate1 =ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
 dtDate2=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

 MsgBox "Days difference: " & CStr(daysRem(dtDate1, dtDate2)), vbInformation

End Sub
```

Call it from a button_click event

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out.  Unfortunately, I don't think this is what I'm trying to learn to do.   The exact wording of what I'm supposed to do is below:


1. Create function macro that returns the number of days left until the end of the class

2. Use the function to estimate the number of class meetings left in the year (e.g. divide by 7 to get weeks and multiply by 2 to get class meetings. 

3. Create a sub that results in a message box that says “Only 90 days until classes end. That is approximately N classes.” The sub should call the function.

Comment: Please add a small sample of your data. Where are these dates located? In a workbook or table? How many rows? Date 1 is Today's date I assume. But where is Date2? Please clarify

Comment: Thanks @M.R.

This is a simple excel sheet.  You input the dates in cells A2 & B2.  Cell C2 tells you the days between them (by using my custom function), and a message box pops up telling you the number of weeks.

This isn't a real world thing.  I know there are 500 ways to do this easier, but the point is to learn how to pass the date I calculated in my macro function to the sub.

Comment: You can add a button to call the macro and take the inputs from Cells A2 and B2. See my revised answer

Comment: Thanks so much M.R.  You've been a great help, although I don't think I've been able to communicate effectively with you.  

The point of this is not to come up with dates and weeks.  If that was all I needed to do, a simple Excel formula would be more than sufficient.  

The point of this is to learn to pass information from a Function to a Sub.

Your code is wonderful because it does everything in one neat little sub, but that's not what I'm trying to do here.  

Thanks anyways.  O

Answer (score -3):

```
Sub Main
    x = MyFunction(Param1)
End Sub

MyFunction(MyDate as Date)
    MyFunction = DateDiff("ww", Date(), MyDate)
End Function
```

You assign the value to the function name. The inbuilt `Date()` function is todays date.

Functions return something. Subs don't. Macros ARE SUBS.

Functions return something.

So

```
Function Test
    Test = 5
End Function

Sub Main
    x = Test() + 5
End Sub
```

So **x = 10**.

```
Sub Main
    Param1 = #2/2/2017#  
    Range("B4").Value = MyFunction(Param1)
End Sub

MyFunction(MyDate as Date)
    MyFunction = DateDiff("ww", Date(), MyDate)
End Function
```

Date is both a data type and a function. One doesn't have brackets and one does.

Comment: Should probably be "ww" in double quotes in Excel VBA.

Comment: Hi @M.R. thanks for your continued help.  I don't believe it should be "ww" though.  The point is to get the number of days THEN calculate the number of weeks. I need the days.

Comment: First see if the functionality I suggested above works. Add a button and call the macro in the _click event.

Comment: Thanks MR.  I don't think we're on the same wavelength here.  I really, really do appreciate you taking the time to try to help me.  I'm probably just too much of a novice to understand the good advice you're giving (this is the first VBA I've ever written).  Thanks again.

Comment: No your question is about how to call functions. **Title** = *VBA Basics - Calling Function From a Sub* **Opening statement** = *Now, I need to "Call" that function from a Sub*.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my question is about.  How to call a function from a sub.  I have a function that gives me a value - I need to use that value in a sub.  That's it.  Did I say anything different?

Comment: x holds the answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute.  It's appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, your code doesn't work.  Compile error: variable not defined.

Comment: You have configured it not to work. The code does work. Turn off *Require Variable Declaration* in Tools menu - Options.

Comment: You are correct.  That fixed your code.  Here's what is killing me: why does your code work, but my slightly modified version not?

`Function daysRem(today As Date, eoc As Date) As Integer  `  
    `daysRem = Abs(DateDiff("d", today, eoc))  `
`End Function  `

`Sub Main()  `
    `Range("B4").Value = daysRem() + 5   ` 
`End Sub`

I get "compile error: argument not optional"

Comment: You are specifying in the function definition (`Function daysRem(today As Date, eoc As Date) As Integer`) that the function takes two dates and returns a whole number. When you call it you must call it with two dates. `Range("B4").Value daysRem(Date1, Date2) + 5`

Comment: @Joseph whatever you do, **NEVER** turn off *Require Variable Declaration* in Tools/Options. I cannot fathom a single valid reason to willingly disable this, or worse to omit or (gasp..) *remove* `Option Explicit` at the top of a module. Not one. Instead of allowing the compiler to go ahead and run code riddled with typos and undeclared variables, you *declare every single variable* - `Dim x As Long`, *then* you can do `x = Whatever`. Use `Option Explicit`. Not requiring explicit variable declarations is *begging* for stupid crazy-hard-to-find bugs to happen.

Comment: *Require Variable Declaration* is the same as `option explicit`. You'll note most sample code does not use declared variables. It's really a performance thing. Its also overkill for macros.

Comment: Thank you for the hand holding @CatInLove.  What you said makes a lot of sense.  

 I changed the Sub Main() code to  Range("B4").Value = daysRem(today, eoc) / 7 and got the following compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

Any ideas what that's about?

Comment: There are not defined. Use `Date()` for todays date instead of today. `Date()` as it a inbuilt function that takes nothing and returns todays date. You'll have to work out where the date for eoc will come from. You haven't told us. For an example use `eoc = Date() - 10`. And your function should return 10. Dates are stored as floating point numbers (ie doubles) where the whole number is days since 1601 (I think) and the decimal is the percentage of the day. To enter dates don't use string literals but use date literals, ie `eoc = #31/12/2017#`.

Comment: You're trolling, right? You're delegating to runtime the creation of some on-the-fly undeclared `Variant` that's incurring penalty for storage and implicit type conversions with literally anything it's used for. And *that* would be faster than leveraging the actual data types the language is using? This isn't VBScript. People omitting `Option Explicit` come here all the time with the problems it creates. Advising otherwise is outright trolling. If your code has performance problems, find a more efficient algorithm, instead of turning it into a maintainer's minefield.

Comment: How many lines do you think are in the average macro. Plus in basic we teach the basics of the language, all with LET coercion. A professional skill is having a large toolbox of tricks and choosing the right one for the circumstances. Not spouting dogma.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit`. Strongly type your variables, parameters and function returns. That's not dogma, that's saving you, and your future you, hours of debugging, and avoiding subtle errors that might go unnoticed for years.

Comment: Sure. My problem is with instructing a beginner to allow implicit declarations without warning them about the underlying meaning and implications of that.

Comment: Thank you again.  EOC means end of class - it is manually typed into the excel sheet (cell b1).  I just tried putting the following code in the function and it broke it.  daysRem = Abs(DateDiff("d", Date, eoc))

I wish I could say I was less confused now than before.  How is 2 lines of code so difficult for me?  Literally, this is 2 lines of code and I've been at it for 5 hours now.